# How to make Switch in voidfunction Java

Tags: java, function, switch-statement

EDITED : ALREADY DONE THANKS GUYS

Hello guys am just a newbie. I need to put this calculator with switch in a function. I need to convert it to void function (if that's what it is called). It already worked but the thing is it runs twice. I just putted addition to make my code short but I need it with other operations as well. If anyone know please post it. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Cal {

  static char Switch() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    System.out.println("1]Addition");
    System.out.println("2]Subtraction");
    System.out.println("3]Multiplication");
    System.out.println("4]Division");
    System.out.print("\nEnter Your Choice : ");
    char r = br.readLine().charAt(0);

    switch (r) {
      case '1':
        Add1();
        Add2();
        break;
      default:
        System.out.print("Error");
        break;

    }
    return r;
  }


  static int Add1() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("\nAddition");
    System.out.print("enter 1st # : ");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    return x;
  }

  static int Add2() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("enter 2nd # : ");
    int y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    return y;

  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int y;
    int x;
    char r;
    r = Switch();
    x = Add1();
    y = Add2();
    System.out.print("\nSum " + (x + y));


  }
}
```

Comment: `static void ... // return r;` What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

well the method would become

```
static void Switch()throws IOException{
```

and you change all the `return r;` to just `return;`

and in you `main` you would simply do

```
    Switch();
    System.out.print("\nSum " + (x+y));
```

But x and y need to be moved to be class variables too

Comment: already did it do you know how to put do while in function statement it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is run *twice* is because you call Add1() and Add2()

1. from the `Switch()` method **and**
2. from the `main()` method again.

`Switch()`:

```
    switch (r) {
      case '1':
        Add1();
        Add2();
        break;
```

`main()`:

```
    r = Switch();
    x = Add1();
    y = Add2();
```

Comment: already did it do you know how to put do while in function statement it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. addition should be one single method, not two methods.
Another issue, you do return values, but you don't store the returned values anywhere.

A better approach would be:

```
switch (r) {
      case '1':
        addition();
        break;
      default: //
        break;
}

// ...

private int resultOfAddition;

public void addition(){
  try{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("\nAddition");
    System.out.print("enter 1st # : ");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.print("enter 2nd # : ");
    int y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    this.resultOfAddition = (x+y);

  }
  catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  //  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

//int y;
//    int x;
    char r =  'y';
    while (r!='x'){Switch();} // assuming you want the user to quit once entered x

//    x = Add1();
//    y = Add2();
    System.out.print("\nSum " + (resultOfAddition));
  }
```

Comment: it worked not my only problem is do while.
do you know how where to put it i should put it so i can re run my code without closing it.

Comment: refactor your main method. You are calling your addition both from the switch statement, and from the main method.
what you want, is someting in the lines of what I added in the edit of my reply.
In the main method, I commented out what shouldn't be there. take a look at that, and see if you understand why those lines aren't needed.

Comment: x = Add1(); <- this makes my program run twice thanks for poiting it it work very well now can u add a do while on your code cos i dont know how so i can rerun the code.like this " Try Another Y/N : "

Comment: supahraleiigh: check the main method, there is a loop iteration. if you want to add that, just change the while(r!= 'x') to while(r!='n' && r!= 'N') or something similar.

Comment: But it automatic exits or resumes i need the option if you want to resume or not with that message >.<

Comment: like this  do{ System.out.print("\n\nTry Again Y/N : ");
   y = br.readLine().charAt(0);
   }while(y!='n' && y!='N');

Comment: So, just add that to your menu prints. What's the difficulty?

Comment: Edited: it works thanks i justt puted do{ whiles instead of while that u puted

Comment: In the current code (as far as I've seen/edited it), there is no functional difference between the do-while and the while, but that doesn't mean you 'll never encounter code where there isn't a difference. Make sure you don't automatically use the do-while always, but decide between them based on the rest of the application.